# Moving trucks in an given order supply chain

Tags: anylogic

I created a supply chain model with trucks. Now i created a state chart in the truck agent. The command moveTo is only realizable with an agent.  I would like to make trucks moving to a given tour with destinations in a given order. Can i make a truck moving to destinations in an arraylist ? Or is there another way ? I already tried

```
moveTo(main.tourCollection);
```

Thanks a lot for answer.

Comment: Could you add a more complete example of code ?

Comment: it is short code in the statechart. the command moveTo is just for the type agents. Is this command applicabel for agents or is there a other way the realize that

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only one who doesn't understand the question...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the truck to move to each agent contained in tourCollection one destination after the other. So do this:

1) tourCollection must be an ArrayList with Element type equal to yourAgent (whatever that agent is)
[image: collection]

2) create a variable of type int with initial value 0, let's call it counter

3) Add a statechart as follows in the truck agent:
[image: statechart]

4) In each state you will add the code `moveTo(main.tourCollection.get(counter));`
In each transition you will add the code `counter++;`

5) When counter equals tourCollection.size() you move to a different state, since you have nowhere to move to anymore

Comment: thanks a lot. this answer goes definitely in to the right direction